# Google Pixel XL; Anyone know what this middle piece is called and what it does?

Tags: proximity-sensor, cellphone

Does anyone know what this middle piece is called in the Google Pixel XL?

Here is the image (I've underlined in blue):

[image]

I noticed that it emits infrared light. I think its a proximity sensor but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's the laser autofocus for the main camera.